# Integration of a Function over 7-Sphere

Tags: integration, lebesgue-measure, harmonic-analysis, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Suppose we have  $x_1^2 + y_1^2 + x_2^2 + y_2^2 + x_3^2 + y_3^2 + x_4^2 + y_4^2 = 1$  and we define  $z_j = x_j + iy_j$,  where  $j = 1,\,2,\,3,\,4$.

The problem is finding or approximating the following integral (The actual problem is more complex than this !)
$$I(k) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{S}^7}|(z_1z_4 - z_2z_3)^k|$$,
where $\mathbb{S}^7$ is a $7$-Sphere, and the integral is over its Surface measure. The ultimate aim is to find or get an estimate of the ratios of the type  $\displaystyle \frac{I(k)}{I(k+1)}$

I have never done an Integration over such a surface, the hypersphere and don't know where to begin. Any hint or any pointers would really help me to get started.

(I have been suggested to make use of the fact that the points $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s lie on a sphere; hence we can use it to reduce one variable and make use of Fubini's Theorem with proper limits for integration to proceed. But I can't see how to make use of this.)

---

What have I done till now?

As the problem say, it would be acceptable if we can approximate the ratios or the integral, so
$$|z_1z_4 - z_2z_3| \, \leq \, |z_1z_4| + |z_2z_3| \, = \, |z_1||z_4| + |z_2||z_3|$$
This converts everything into real variables and then I have used Mathematica to calculate this. But the problem is Mathematica gives the solution for small values of  $k$, but as I have to find it for the general case, it is not of much use.

Also, I have tried using the spherical coordinates to help with the integral but they make it more complicated.

Any pointers on this front are also welcome.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393706/integration-of-a-function-over-7-sphere